# C++ compile flags

Tags: c++

For my C++ binaries to work on RH7 or RH6 I was using static compilation using:

```
g++ -I../../ -Wall -std=c++11 -O0 -DSF_VISIBILITY -fvisibility=hidden -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -c -o test.o test.cpp
```

After new OS rhel7.9 I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could you kindly help on what could be missing from the installation?

Comment: Show your full command line.

Comment: g++ -I../../ -Wall -std=c++11 -O0 -DSF_VISIBILITY -fvisibility=hidden -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++   -c -o test.o test.cpp

Comment: How is it that you are passing `-c` for "compile only, don't link" but still get linking errors?  Do you have a separate linking step?

Comment: Hi Selbie, my apologies: g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wunused -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-parameter -Wlong-long -I../../ -Wall -std=c++11 -O0 -DSF_VISIBILITY -fvisibility=hidden -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o main_binary test.o after test.o is compiled

Comment: My guess is you have missed some dependencies on your new RHEL installations.
Try:
sudo yum install glibc-static libstdc++-static -y